# What is the use of angle quotes when extedning a JAVA class to its nested class? (example inside)

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-recyclerview

I came across a syntax that I can not understand and I can't find more info by searching. In the example below the CarAdapter class extends to  RecyclerView.Adapter but furthermore there is something in angle quotes `<CarAdapter.ViewHolder>` which points to a nested class ViewHolder.

```
public class CarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarAdapter.ViewHolder>
    {          
              {
                // ..... code here
              }
         public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                    {
                           public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                           super(itemView);
                           // ....Code Here
                            }
                    }
    }
```

I can't quite interpret the section that extends the class to the `<CarAdapter.ViewHolder>`, but this syntax works in some RecyclerView examples I came across lately. Any ideas?

Thank you for being in this wonderful community.

Comment: Do you know about generic types?

Comment: THis is about generics.  When you see this, it means that its taking a class with generics and its extending it to work with a specific class, rather than keeping it generic.  I suggest reading up on the concept, its worth more study than an SO answer can give.

Comment: This is just Java's syntax for a rank-1 parametrically polymorphic type constructor.